# Use function-pointer as proxy to member-function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Assume a class like this:

```
class Speaker {
    public:
        void (*saySomething)();
}
```

The point is that we can instantiate that class and call the stored function pointer in order to make it say something (whatever that turns out to be). The background to such an approach is to have the actual function reside in a shared library and `Speaker` acts as some sort of wrapper class (The function gets resolved in the library and the pointer is assigned to the variable in the class).

Now consider we have another class that extends `Speaker`:

```
class ConstantSpeaker : public Speaker {
    protected:
        std::string message;
        void doSpeak();
}
```

with the method's implementation like this:

```
ConstantSpeaker::doSpeak() {
    std::cout << message << std:endl;
}
```

Now I want to assign the `saySomething` pointer in a way so that the call is somehow re-routed to `ConstantSpeaker::doSpeak()`. This however isn't possible directly as `doSpeak()` is a member function and `saySomething` is a pointer to a non-member-function.
Another idea I had was to create `doSpeak()` as a friend-function of `ConstantSpeaker` instead. Then the pointer-assignment works fine but now `doSpeak()` would require the object holding the actual message as an argument in order to be able to access the message.

To me it seems as if there should be a (more or less) straight-forward way of doing this given that I can only ever call `Speaker::saySomething` when having an instance of a `Speaker` at hand. Therefore the availability of the corresponding object shouldn't be a problem but still I can't figure out how I have to assign that pointer.

The only solution I could come up with is to add a public `virtual Speaker::doSaySomething` function whose implementation will call the function pointer (which is then no longer public in order to prevent miss-usage) and that can be overwritten by `ConstantSpeaker` to call `ConstantSpeaker::doSpeak()` instead.
Is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: Bad design of callback in the library... *If* you can modify it, make it accept a pointer to void, and instead of `registerCallback(void(*)(void))`, you'd have `registerCallback(void(*function)(void*), void* parameter)`. If you cannot, possibly fall back to a static pointer variable `registeredInstance`? Ugly, sure, but nothing better in mind either...

Comment: @n.m. yeah I was suspecting that this can't really be done but I wanted to see if there was a neat trick that could be used for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is just to use a standard `std::function<void()>`, and then it can be still declared as public.

Also, instead of bare function pointer, you can use pointer to member function, but be aware about slicing, when using it inside a base class.

But, I think, the most trivial way of doing this is just by using `virtual` function, like you've mentioned.

Maybe tell more about your context? What is the problem you are going to solve?

Comment: The context more or less is how I described it in the question: I want a wrapper function for functions living inside a shared library. However I know that I'll have to deal with backwards-compatibility of libraries that contain different functions but I still want to use the corresponding wrapper-class the same way as the normal wrapper class handling all compatibility in the derived wrapper-class.

Comment: If noone can come up with a better solution, I'll mark this as the accepted answer. I already suspected that it can't be done properly otherwise...

Comment: I agree on the virtual function. Member function pointer doesn't allow to store the non-member function again, `std::function` comes with quite some overhead that doesn't seem to pay off for the problem in question (it's more generic than it needs to be).